# Goldstone bosons, quark and gluon masses counting in color-flavor locking QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, phase-diagram

Consider QCD, with three flavors of massless quarks, we like to focus on the possible Cooper paired phases.

For 3 quarks $(u,c,d)$ and 3 colors $(r,g,b)$, the Cooper pairs cannot be flavor singlets, and both color and flavor symmetries are broken. The attractive channel favored by
1-gluon exchange is known as “color-flavor locking.” A condensate involving left-handed quarks alone locks $SU(3)_L$ flavor rotations to $SU(3)_{color}$, in the sense that the condensate is not symmetric under either alone, but is symmetric under the simultaneous $SU(3)_{L+color}$ rotations. A condensate involving right-handed quarks alone locks $SU(3)_R$ flavor rotations to
$SU(3)_{color}$. Because color is vectorial, the result is to breaking chiral symmetry. Thus, in quark matter with three massless quarks, the $SU(3)_{color} \times SU(3)_L  \times SU(3)_R  \times U(1)_B$ (the last one is baryon) symmetry is broken down to the global diagonal $SU(3)_{color+L+R}$ group.

question:

1) How many quarks among nine ($(u,c,d) \times (r,g,b)$) have a dynamical energy gap? What are they?

2) How many among the eight gluons get a mass?  What are they?

3) How many massless Nambu-Goldstone bosons there are? What are they? How to describe them?

Comment: This looks rather like a "homework" question, although very advanced. This is not a homework help site - we do not do your assignments for you.  Please **show your attempt** to answer these questions, and ask about a **conceptual difficulty**.

Comment: @ sammy gerbil, your comment is very abusive and wronged. It is absolutely not a homework question --- just an extended question from reading the Wikipedia. And it is 100% not a homework question that a professor ever assigns to you . Otherwise can you answer? Other than saying this agressive words out of nowhere?

Comment: The mid paragraph and the formulation of this question are my attempt to answer the question. The Goldstone theorem tells us that the Goldstone boson lives on the coset space of |original group/unbroken group|, but for this example, it is subtler because Goldstone boson can be eaten by gauge fields. So this counting is more subtle. I have my own counting, but I do not like to bias the readers. Also I do not know it is correct.

Comment: maybe then you should edit your question and add details to highlight your conceptual difficulties...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions are answered in the original literature:

1) All quarks are gapped. The nine quarks arrange themselves into an octet with gap $\Delta$ and a singlet with gap $2\Delta$.

2) All gluons are gapped.

3) There is an octet of Goldstone bosons related to chiral symmetry breaking, and a singlet associated with $U(1)$ breaking.

Postscript:

i) When pair condensates form there is a gap in the excitation spectrum of single quarks (this is just regular BCS). However, the gapped excitations may be linear combinations of the microscopic quark fields. In the present case the nine types of quark fields ($N_c\times N_f=9$), form an octet and a singlet of an unbroken $SU(3)$ color-flavor symmetry.

ii) Pair condensation and the formation of a gap take place near the Fermi surface. There is no Fermi surface for anti-quarks (if $\mu$ is positive and large), and therefore no pairing and no gaps.

iii) There is both a $U(1)$ GB (associated with the broken $U(1)_B$) and a masssless $U(1)$ gauge boson (associated with the $U(1)_{Q}$ gauge symmetry that is not Higgsed).

iv) The [8] GB correspond to spontaneous breaking of chiral symmetry. In ordinary QCD these would be quark-anti-quark states, but at high density anti-quarks decouple. A detailed analysis shows that the GBs are predominantly 2-particle-2-hole states, $(qq)(\bar{q}\bar{q})$.

Comment: Thanks but can you count carefully? See that ((u,c,d)×(r,g,b)x(anti colors)) -- do they have more than 9 quarks?

Comment: This is very dense matter, made of quarks. It is reasonable to ask if quarks have gaps, because quarks near the Fermi surface are long-lived quasi-particles. But anti-quarks are far off-shell, and it is not clear what we might mean by anti-quark gaps.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, +1, it looks you are knowledgeable in some way.

Comment: But $SU(3)_{color} \times SU(3)_L  \times SU(3)_R  \times U(1)_B$   symmetry has $8*3+1=25$ generators, is broken down to the global diagonal $SU(3)_{color+L+R}$ which has 8 generators. Thus the maximum Goldstone bosons should be $25-8=17$.  Am I understand correctly that 17 Goldstone bosons equal to your 8 (gives mass to 8 gluons)+8 (Octave Goldstone)+1 (massless Goldstone of U(1))? So $$17=8+8+1,$$correct?

Comment: And the quark masses are dynamically generated, which have nothing to do with the Goldstone counting, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, one octet eaten by Higgs mechanism, and quark gaps generated as in BCS.

Comment: But my second octave Goldstone bosons all survive to produce massless modes. You should update your answer with more clarity, otherwise I will write an answer myself. ;)

Comment: No, eaten by Higgs mecahnism.

Comment: Here is what I mean: I thought my first octave Goldstone bosons are eaten by gluons (thus gluons are Higgsed), and my second octave Goldstone bosons all survive to produce massless modes.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, one octet eaten by Higgs mechanism, one octet produces Goldstone bosons. Evene simpler: Only global symmetries produce GBs. We have $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R\times U(1)\to SU(3)_F$, corresponding to [8] +[1] Gbs.

Comment: Concern 17=8+8+1,

“All quarks are gapped. The nine quarks arrange themselves into an octet with gap Δ and a singlet with gap 2Δ.” The superconducting gap are paired of quarks instead of individual quarks. So what do you mean by nine quarks are gapped? Also quark-quark Cooper pair <qq> also implies **anti-quark-anti-quark <q ̄q ̄> can form a Cooper pair**, isnt’t it? So what exactly are the 9 different gaps you are talking about from (physical indices)?

Comment: Once we are in CFL, it may not be useful to talk about the individual quarks, no? But instead quark pairs?

Comment: am still confused by what you said. Is the 9 Goldstone modes containing 8 mesons? But here we are in CFL that has no Chiral Symmetry Breaking, so why do we have mesons? I thought we do NOT have 8 “massless” mesons as Goldstone modes? So what exactly are Goldstone modes here, within superconducting gap 2Δ?

Comment: Is the remained 1 mode from U(1) a Goldstone mode of a gluon-photon mixture? Why or why not?

Comment: @annieheart  I added a postcsript.

Comment: Thanks, but you havent explained the physical meanings of all the Goldstone modes (8+1=9)?

Comment: @Thomas, nice discussions, the  [8] +[1] Goldstone bosons here are spin-0 scalars, aren't they? They have nothing to do with the un-Higgised spin-1 gluon-photon mixture, yes? So what are [8] +[1] Goldstone bosons, physically, in terms of spin-0 quark-pair condensate, yes or no?

Comment: @annieheart More edits.

Comment: Thanks, but how about the [1] Goldstone mode? Is that spin-0 particle? what is it?

Comment: The usual superfluid GB mode from breaking U(1)_B

Comment: Can I think of it as some kinds of phonons in QCD? I mean how do I write down [1] Goldstone mode from using QCD Lagrangian?

Comment: Also do you see that all the quark pair condensate need to be Lorentz scalar instead of Lorentz pseudo-scalar ? or even non-relativistic scalar only?

Comment: Goldstone mode is derivatively coupled to baryon current, $\bar{q}\gamma_\mu q\sim f\partial_\mu\phi$.

Comment: ok, which best short Ref are you looking at for this?

Comment: @Thomas, I am puzzled by one thing. If we have a two quark condensation $<qq>\neq 0$, isnt that implying that we need its Hermitian conjugate $<\bar{q}\bar{q}>\neq 0$ as well? But the interpretation of $<\bar{q}\bar{q}>\neq 0$ could be that the two quark "hole" pair condense. Isn"t that the same thing as two anti-quark condensation?

Comment: @Thomas Namely, $<\bar{q}\bar{q}>\neq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ two quark "hole" pair condense $\Leftrightarrow$ two anti-quark condensation? So why do we dont encounter two anti-quark condensation in your answer?

Comment: @annieheart  Quarks are Dirac fermions, so the the $qq$ condensate is a $4\times 4$ matrix. These components can be interpreted as quark-quark, hole-hole, anti-quark-anti-quark , anti-hole-anti-hole pairing. Near the Fermi surface we get quark-quark and hole-hole, but anti-quark or anti-hole pairing.

Comment: @  Thomas, Are you sure what you are writing " Near the Fermi surface we get quark-quark and hole-hole, but anti-quark or anti-hole pairing" ???

Comment: Should be  .. but not ..

Comment: @Thomas, you may shed light on this too -- I guess you know the full answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376164

Comment: For some reason, I still do not understand where can I find this Ref on your "iv) The [8] GB correspond to spontaneous breaking of chiral symmetry. In ordinary QCD these would be quark-anti-quark states, but at high density anti-quarks decouple. A detailed analysis shows that the GBs are predominantly 2-particle-2-hole states, $(qq)(\bar{q}\bar{q})$."

Comment: Can you please illuminate why is that the case and give a Ref?

Comment: This was noticed in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9908227 and is described in standard review, for example Sect V.C in https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4635

Comment: The basic point is that in ordinary QCD the object that condenses are $q\bar{q}$ pairs, and GB are chiral rotations of the condensate. In high density QCD the basic condensates are pairs of particles and holes, $(qq)$ and $(\bar{q}\bar{q})$. Now I notice that a $(qq)$ in the $\bar{3}$ of color and flavor transforms just like a single $\bar{q}$ and the $(\bar{q}\bar{q})$ transforms like a single $q$. This means I can construct a GB field that transforms like the usual one, but the microscopic content is $(qq)(\bar{q}\bar{q})$.