# gauge-invariant 6-quark order parameter

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking

In this Review paper in p.1462,  bottom left: [Rev.Mod.Phys.80:1455-1515,2008 -- Color superconductivity in dense quark matter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e2d/7720d397f1618637e5ca6acaf9ead1992478.pdf)

It says that "There is an associated gauge-invariant 6-quark order parameter with the flavor and color structure of two Lambda baryons,
$$
\langle\Lambda\Lambda\rangle
$$
where
this order parameter distinguishes the color flavor locking (CFL) phase from the quark gluon plsma QGP.

> I suppose that it means the 6 quark condensate is
>   $$
> \bigl\langle(\epsilon^{abc}\epsilon_{ijk}\psi^a_i\psi^b_j\psi^c_k)
> (\epsilon^{a'b'c'}\epsilon_{i'j'k'}\psi'^a_i\psi'^b_j\psi'^c_k)\bigr\rangle,
> $$
>
> 1. but how does this distinguish CFL from QGP?
> 2. Is this operator precise? And is this gauge invariant under SU(3)???
> 3. It is a Lorentz scalar or pseudo scalar?

It seems that the claim is not clear.

Comment: It looks gauge invariant, because $\epsilon$ tensor is SU(3) invariant. About the Lorentz structure, there is a problem with your expression. You have $6$ $\psi$ fields and no $\bar \psi$. Therefore I think this correlation function vanishes. Perhaps you meant something like $\bar \psi^3 \psi^3$. In this case you still need to specify what you do with bispinor indices of $\psi$ and $\bar \psi$.

Comment: can we show ϵ tensor is SU(3) singlet?

Comment: Yes, the $\epsilon$ tensor is how one constructs a singlet out of fundamentals.  Georgi's group theory book might be a useful place to check this out if it isn't familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It breaks $U(1)_B$, and therefore distinguished QGP from CFL.
2. Yes, this is a gauge invariant operator.
3. This is a Lorentz scalar if the spinors are contracted appropriately, for example
   $$
   \phi \sim \epsilon_{\alpha\alpha'}\epsilon_{\beta\gamma}\epsilon_{\beta'\gamma'}
    (\psi_\alpha\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma)(\psi_{\alpha'}\psi_{\beta'}\psi_{\gamma'})
   $$
   In 4-component notation this can be written in terms of a (positive parity) baryon current
   $$
   \phi \sim \Psi C\gamma_5 \Psi, \qquad\Psi_\alpha = \psi_\alpha (\psi C\gamma_5\psi)
   $$

Comment: thanks +1, is this 6-quark term related to breaking the axial $Z_6$ of QGP to the $Z_2$ vector symmetry (same as axial) of CFL? or am I wrong???

Comment: how do one contracts? you said: "This is a Lorentz scalar if the spinors are contracted appropriately." Do we need some gamma matrices?

Comment: also, how about this one? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376203

Comment: Instantons break $U(1)_A$ to $Z_6$ in both the QGP and CFL. CFL further breaks $Z_6$ to $Z_2$, but this is not seen from this order parameter. One way to see this is to observe that in CFL chiral symmetry is broken, and $\langle \bar\psi_L\psi_R\rangle$ is not zero.

Comment: so what is the symmetry of this order parameter bring down? Is that $SU(3)_{L+R+C} \times Z_{6}$?

Comment: Each baryon like operator either has spin 1/2 or spin 3/2. How should I understand your indices contraction in terms of spin objects? The total spin should be 0, but contracting from spin 1/2 and spin 1/2?

Comment: @ Thomas, are you writing a 2-component spinor indices to contract with $\epsilon_{12}=-\epsilon_{21}=1$? And how is that correspond to spin 1/2 pairing mechanism?

Comment: This is meant to be 2-component spinor notation. Then $\Psi_\alpha=\epsilon_{\beta\gamma}\psi_\alpha\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma$ is a spin 1/2 nucleon field (because $\Phi=\epsilon_{\beta\gamma}\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma$ is a spin 0 diquark). Taking a spin singlet combination of two nucleon fields gives a scalar order parameter.

Comment: @ Thomas, one more clarification, in this $
\epsilon_{\alpha\alpha'}\epsilon_{\beta\gamma}\epsilon_{\beta'\gamma'}
 (\psi_\alpha\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma)(\psi_{\alpha'}\psi_{\beta'}\psi_{\gamma'})
$, must I have  $(\psi_\alpha\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma)$ as the 1st baryon and $(\psi_{\alpha'}\psi_{\beta'}\psi_{\gamma'})$ as the 2nd baryon?

Comment: Can I have  instead $$
\epsilon_{\alpha\alpha'}\epsilon_{\beta \beta'}\epsilon_{\gamma\gamma'}
 (\psi_\alpha\psi_\beta\psi_\gamma)(\psi_{\alpha'}\psi_{\beta'}\psi_{\gamma'})
$$ while the color/flavor indices are given as above? (p.s. am going to accept you as the answer after this)

Comment: Or can I write these scalar in terms of $C \gamma^5$ in4-component spinor notations?

Comment: @ Thomas, I am also curious about the L and R handness indices and properties of parity here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Thomas : In particular, I thought we are considering the Dirac spinor, how does $$\epsilon_{\alpha\alpha'} 
 (\psi_\alpha )(\psi_{\alpha'})$$, $$Ψα=ϵ_{βγ}ψ_αψ_βψ_γ$$  represent which part of Dirac spinor? Or should the baryon composed by three of 2-component Weyl spinor $(\psi_\alpha )$ instead of 4-component Dirac spinor? Thanks!

Comment: @ Thomas, also how is the parity $P$ property of the condensate? (under $L \to R$?) Are there choices?

Comment: @annie heart Added a postscript

Comment: can it be negative parity, too? accepted, but please clarufy.