# quark momentum and quark mass in unpairing and pairing phase

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-chromodynamics

In this Review paper in p.1464,  top left: [Rev.Mod.Phys.80:1455-1515,2008 -- Color superconductivity in dense quark matter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e2d/7720d397f1618637e5ca6acaf9ead1992478.pdf)

It shows a figure of quark momentum of quark $u,d,s$, in unpairing and pairing phase, such that

$$p_d >p_u>p_s$$

however, we know:
$$ m_u<m_d<m_s$$

> so why isnt that
>   $$p_u >p_d>p_s$$
>   if momentum is inverse proportional to the quark mass? What is going on here for these quark momentum?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We usually consider electrically neutral matter (because charged matter cannot exist in a macroscopic system -- the Coulomb energy diverges with the volume). In principle $uds$ matter with a deficit of strange quarks (because of the heavier strange quark) can be neutralized by electrons, but it is energetically favorable to neutralize by an excess of $d$ quarks (also negatively charged). The reason is that reference state, neutral matter with equal Fermi momenta for $u,d,s$ quarks, has a large Fermi momentum for down quarks, but zero Fermi momentum for electrons. A small shift in the chemical potentials then leads to a large shift of the down quark abundance, but only a small shift in the electron abundance.