# Quark pair superconductor: Even parity is favorred than odd parity

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-chromodynamics, instantons

It seems that the quark pair superconductor can be odd or even parity pairing respect to the parity $P$.

Say that the even parity has the form:
$$
\langle\psi C \gamma^5 \psi\rangle
$$

the odd parity has the form:
$$
\langle\psi C   \psi\rangle
$$
There is no difference at perturbative computation. $C$ is charge conjugate matrix.

But the literature seems to suggest that instanton effect favors the even parity not the odd parity. I look into the literature but the original paper seems not to assert that claim. [Refs cited here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_superconductivity)

Do you have either a simple and intuitive or a rigorous analytic explanation of the claim?

Answer (score 2):

This requires an actual calculation (and getting the signs right), see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9810509 .

There are some simple heuristics. For example, there is a successful quark-scalar-diquark model of the nucleon. Lattice QCD practioners know that the nucleon couples strongly to 
$$
\eta_S = \psi (\psi C\gamma_5 C) 
$$
but not to 
$$
\eta_{PS} = \gamma_5\psi ( \psi C\psi)
$$

Comment: Thanks, you final form is kind of abstrat, not sure what it implies...

Comment: +1, but do you agree that the gap function in $k$ space has $\Delta(k)=-\Delta(k)$ for even parity, and $\Delta(k)=+\Delta(k)$ for odd parity? This is kind of counter intuition but I wanted to make sure your odd even parity means the same thing

Comment: No, there is no difference in the symmetry of the gap function. This is just a relative phase. The two order parameters are $\psi_L\psi_L\pm \psi_R\psi_R$.

Comment: but when you convert to the k space, like in the BdG equation, you should see the potential difference of $\Delta(k)$. See any condensed matter BdG equation.

Comment: No. The $J^\pi=0^\pm$ order parameters have the same gap function. The simplest way to get an odd gap function is to consider $p$ wave pairing, $J^\pi=1^\pm$.